# Find out if a value exist in previous 2 rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df which I would like to find in that value is duplicated in the previous 2 rows, among every selected column. How should I do it?

In excel, I can do it by =if(countif(A1:B2,C1),"True","False")

```py
c = {'N1': [1,1,2,3,4,4,5],'N2': [2,3,4,4,5,6,7],'N3':[3,7,5,5,6,7,8],}
df = pd.DataFrame(c, columns=['N1','N2','N3'])
```

## Expected Result:

```py
c = {'N1': [1,1,2,3,4,4,5],'N2': [2,3,4,4,5,6,7],'N3':[3,7,5,5,6,7,8],
     "Result1":['NA','NA','True','True','True','True','True'],
     "Result2":['NA','NA','False','True','True','True','True'],
     "Result3":['NA','NA','False','True','False','False','False']}
df = pd.DataFrame(c, columns=['N1','N2','N3','Result1','Result2','Result3'])
```

Expected result as above.

Comment: What have you done so far? Please provide a code snippet as a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to make helping you easier since SO is not a code writing platform/service.

Comment: Your excel function is not match what you described

Comment: I'm very confused

Answer (score 1):

Create another DataFrame that has 2 shifts, then check if the value of each column is found in any of those 6 values.

```
u = pd.concat([df.shift(x) for x in range(1, 3)], axis=1, ignore_index=True)

for i in range(df.shape[1]):
    df[f'Result{i+1}'] = u.eq(df.iloc[:, i], axis=0).any(1)

cols = [x for x in df.columns if 'Result' in x]
df.loc[s.isnull().any(1), cols] = 'NA'

   N1  N2  N3 Result1 Result2 Result3
0   1   2   3      NA      NA      NA
1   1   3   7      NA      NA      NA
2   2   4   5    True   False   False
3   3   4   5    True    True    True
4   4   5   6    True    True   False
5   4   6   7    True    True   False
6   5   7   8    True    True   False
```